# what are some resources to learn about copyright law?

Tags: open-source

I once heard a prominent scientist say, of global warming, that he didn't realize how much he would have to learn about politics.

I just read an excellent article in DDJ about the [Jacobsen verus Katzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobsen_v._Katzer) case. When in university, I didn't know how much ***I*** would have to learn about the law.

It seems to me that a big hole in the classic comp sci education is that of legal issues.  Many of us talk about licenses, copyright, copyleft, prior art, etc, but our terms are often vague and probably inaccurate.

What are some resources where the average developer can learn about copyright law and become an informed citizen of IT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[groklaw](http://www.groklaw.net/) would seem to be a good starting point for open source issues

Answer (score 1):

1 A good overview of key intellectual property regimes (more geared to open source, US law) can be found here:

http://www.softwarefreedom.org/resources/2008/foss-primer.html

2 Here's also a collection of links to open educational materials on digital copyright:

https://sites.google.com/site/copyrightessentials/

I'd also recommend reading the materials on the Electronic Frontier Foundation's website, regularly updated and high quality.

Answer (score 0):

The Nolo book *Legal Guide to Web & Software Development* discusses copyright and other issues as they pertain to software developers.

[http://www.amazon.com/Legal-Guide-Software-Development-CD-Rom/dp/1413305326/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1413305326)

Answer (score 0):

I really enjoyed [these lectures](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-912January--IAP--2006/CourseHome/) from MIT Open Courseware.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any truly greate resource. I just know that most of what I've seen is missinformation, even by people who should know. So be very sceptical of anything you read.

If you just want to know the practical concrete law of things I suggest you speak to a lawyer and/or read some actual verdicts.

Then again most copyright issues aren't taken to court but affect you more directly in contracts, expectations and litigation threats. In this case the law won't help you, the cultural dealings with copyright will probably differ a great deal from the actual law, in this case it would be better to just study the people/companies and their actions. I recommend the course [COMM 499: PWNED: Is everyone on this campus a copyright criminal?](http://uscpwned.blogspot.com/2007/01/syllabus.html) by Cory Doctorow. You can get recordings of the lectures at [archive.org](http://www.archive.org/search.php?query=doctorow%20pwned)

If you are more interested in ideological issues I think [Question Copyright](http://questioncopyright.org/) has a few interesting articles. Specifically one about the history of copyright.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a company, ask management to have the company’s intellectual property lawyer come in and speak to the technical people.  Although lawyers usually work on an hourly rate basis, the good ones love to come in and give little educational seminars to show their clients they care and, of course, to sensitize them to legal issues that they might call for more help on.